# Getting UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: write EPROTO when running my async await function in NodeJS

Tags: javascript, json, object, async-await, axios

I was running the below code without any issue up until this afternoon, I did not change or update anything, not sure what is causing this:

```
async function getStocks(){

    const { data } = await axios.get('https://gist.githubusercontent.com/graffixnyc/8c363d85e61863ac044097c0d199dbcc/raw/7d79752a9342ac97e4953bce23db0388a39642bf/stocks.json')
    return data // this will be the array of people objects
}

async function abc(){
    let a = await getStocks()
    console.log(a)
}

abc()
```

It used to render the entire data from the JSON file but now throws the below error:

```
(node:1860) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: write EPROTO 14520:error:1408F10B:SSL ` 
routines:ssl3_get_record:wrong version 
number:c:\ws\deps\openssl\openssl\ssl\record\ssl3_record.c:332:`
```

I am not sure which dependency has the wrong version since I did not update the code nor made any changes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The data on the website sent an invalid response, so the issue was not in the code but the website data itself.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding Try Catch to your functions.

Comment: I did, but it does not help

Comment: Did you add try catch on the function call also?

Comment: Yes, I get undefined as the answer